How do I create a wood texture in Adobe Illustrator?
How do I create and apply a wood texture in Adobe Illustrator based on the tree shape as shown in the picture below?


Do you want the tree texture to made of vector elements? Or are you ok with it being an imported raster image?

Can you also [edit] your question to show us what steps have you tried and where did you get stuck? Otherwise this just sounds like a request for free work.

Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

What have you tried?

Find a wood texture either online, take a photo of one, or use Photoshop's generative AI to make one. Then use the Liquify Tool in Photoshop to distort it something like this.

Then draw a tree shape in Illustrator, and use it as a clipping mask on the distorted raster image


The base body is divided to separate stripes which all have separate shadings for apparent differently curved surfaces. In theory they could also have separately distorted texture fills to make the texture to obey the growth direction of the tree. This is my quick test to imitate it with only a few stripes:

The bark texture was borrowed from an advertisement of wood-like wallpaper materials. To make something for sale one should purchase a bark texture image or paint it.
To stay in truth making this in illustrator is far from quick. I cheated and pasted the texture on a simple 3D model of the base part of a tree. It's quick.
In your image the curved surface form of the tree has been shaded quite carefully, but the bark pattern does not obey the growth direction at all. It's not a big harm if the bark texture is contains only small enough details. Even a noise pattern could do the job. In the next image the realistic bark texture is changed to SVG cross-noise:

The grains are too small when compared to the sizes of the tree base shape stripes. The texture photo is far more plausible. The noise could work better if there were more and smaller separately shaded stripes.
The noise texture has one advantage: It doesn't expect any growth direction.
A bit tougher task is to draw the tree and shade the curved surfaces. Here's an attempt to draw a small piece with a couple of branches:

The bark texture is an overlay which is filled with the same SVG cross-noise as used above. In the next image the overlay is moved aside to show the underlying shading:

Blending mode multiply mixes the shading and the overlay.
The shading contains some blurred black shapes which are grouped and clipped with the tree shape. In the next image the clipping mask is released and moved aside:

The shapes of the shading without blur are these:

The edge stroke of the tree shape was cut to pieces. The stroke pieces are edited one by one. They are made longer, converted to outline paths and also made wider here and there. Wider pieces have got more blur.
